# Optimizar código para guardar ordenado

Tags: c++, algoritmos, ordenamiento

Anteriormente hice un código para guardar scores en un archivo `.txt` usando **C++**, pero era malisimo, lo que hacia básicamente era lo siguiente:

1. Obtener todos los scores actuales.
2. Crear un .txt temporal.
3. Ordenarlos.
4. Guardarlos en el temporal.
5. Eliminar el primero.
6. Cambiar el nombre al temporal por el que elimine en el paso 5.

Voy a dejar el código aquí:

```
#include "ScoreManager.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string ScoreManager::file_name = "scores.txt";
ifstream ScoreManager::fs;


ScoreManager::ScoreManager() {}

bool ScoreManager::openFile(const string name, const bool doCheck){

    bool valid_file = true;

    if (doCheck){

        valid_file = false;

        struct stat s;
        if( stat((name).c_str(),&s) == 0 ){
            if( s.st_mode & S_IFDIR ){
                cout<<"The path is a directory. "<<endl;
            }
            else if( s.st_mode & S_IFREG ){
                valid_file = true;
            }else{
                cout<<"The path is not file or directory. "<<endl;
                cout<<"else "<<endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout<<"An error happened as trying to identify the path. "<<endl;
        }
    }

    if (!fs.is_open() && valid_file){
        const char *title = name.c_str();
        fs.open(title);
    }

    return fs.is_open();
}

void ScoreManager::closeFile(){
    if (fs.is_open()){
        fs.close();
    }
}


vector<string> ScoreManager::getListScores(){
    ifstream read;
    vector<Score> scores;
    Score unScore;
    string line, name, score;
    vector<string> myVector;
    file_name = "scores.txt";   

    if (openFile(file_name, false)){
        closeFile();
    }   
    read.open("scores.txt", ios::in);

    while(getline(read, line))
    {
        myVector.push_back(line);
    }
    closeFile();

    return myVector;

}

void ScoreManager::write_file(string pName, int pScore ){

    file_name = "scores.txt";

    if (openFile(file_name, false)){
        closeFile();
    }


    ofstream fl("scores.txt", ios::app); //Abro el archivo y le digo que inserte al final
    ofstream fltemp("temp.txt", ios::app); //Abro el archivo y le digo que inserte al final
    if (fl.is_open() && fltemp.is_open()){
    // ya se puede leer ...
        fl<<pScore<<" "<<pName<<endl; //Guardo el actual
        vector<string> actual = orderList(getListScores()); //Obtengo todos ordenados
         for(int i = 0; i<actual.size(); i++){
            fltemp<<actual[i]<<endl; //Escrito todos en el temporal
        }

    fl.close();    //Cierro el archivo score
    fltemp.close(); //Cierro el archivo temp
    remove("scores.txt"); //Elimino el archivo
    rename("temp.txt", "scores.txt");
    }else
    {
        cout<<"Error al abrir el archivo"<<endl;;
    }
}

vector<string> ScoreManager::orderList(vector<string> pList){

    int i, j;
    string temp;
    for (i=1; i<pList.size(); i++){
          for (j=0 ; j<pList.size() - 1; j++){
               if (getOnlyInt(pList[j]) < getOnlyInt(pList[j+1])){
                    temp = pList[j];
                    pList[j] = pList[j+1];
                    pList[j+1] = temp;}
          }
    }
    return pList;
}

int ScoreManager::getOnlyInt(string pRow){
    int row, i;
    string auxRow;
    for(i = 0; i<pRow.length(); i++){
        if(isdigit(pRow[i])){
            auxRow+=pRow[i];
        }
    }
    row = atoi(auxRow.c_str());
    return row;
}
```

PREGUNTA: Como optimizar este código? o que código haría lo mismo pero sin tantas vueltas como lo hago yo.

Error de la solución de abajo:

```
g++ -std=c++11  -I include/ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/cegui-0/CEGUI -I/usr/local/include/cegui-0 `pkg-config --cflags OGRE OGRE-Overlay OgreBullet bullet`  -g -D_DEBUG -c src/ScoreManager.cpp -o obj/ScoreManager.o `pkg-config --libs-only-l OGRE OgreBullet bullet OGRE-Overlay SDL2_mixer` -lboost_system -lOIS -lGL -lstdc++ -lCEGUIBase-0 -lCEGUIOgreRenderer-0
src/ScoreManager.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ScoreManager::write_file(std::__cxx11::string, int)’:
src/ScoreManager.cpp:105:21: error: cannot call member function ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > ScoreManager::orderList(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&&)’ without object
     orderList(scores);
```

Comment: Y tu pregunta es...?

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta????

Comment: Si la pregunta es "¿Cuál es el algoritmo más eficiente para ordenar una lista?", hay un "librito" de un tal Knuth que se llama "Sorting and Searching" (supongo que habrá alguna edición en castellano) que compara diferentes algoritmos. Sin necesidad de llegar a ese extremo, buscando "algoritmos de ordenación" encontrarás mucha información explicándote qué algoritmos hay, como funcionan y su implementación.

Comment: Como hacer lo mismo pero mas eficiente!! esa es la pregunta!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como optimizar este código?

**Evita copias innecesarias**

```
vector<string> ScoreManager::orderList(vector<string> pList)
```

Pocas cosas hay tan poco óptimas como hacer 1-2 copias de un vector cuando lo cierto es que no necesitas realizar ninguna. Y sí, he dicho dos copias:

```
vector<string> ScoreManager::orderList(vector<string> pList)
// (1)                                      (2)
```

A saber:

1. El objeto que devuelves independiente del objeto pasado como argumento... 1 copia (dependiendo de si se aplica la optimización de *copy elision* esta copia podría llegar a omitirse)
2. El argumento lo pasas por valor... 1 copia

Esta función debería trabajar con 1 sola copia o, idoneamente, con ninguna:

0-1 copia:

```
vector<string> ScoreManager::orderList(vector<string> const& pList)
```

0 copias:

```
// versiones previas a C++11
void ScoreManager::orderList(vector<string> & pList ) 

// C++11 en adelante (sintaxis move)
vector<string> ScoreManager::orderList(vector<string> && pList)
{
  // ...
  return pList; // equivalente a return std::move(pList);
}
```

La implementación de esta función es otra tarea que podría mejorarse... por ejemplo haciendo uso de la STL:

```
// C++11 en adelante
vector<string> ScoreManager::orderList(vector<string> && pList){
  std::sort(pList.begin(),pList.end(),
            [this](string const& s1, string const& s2)
            { return getOnlyInt(s1) < getOnlyInt(s2); });

  return pList;
}
```

**Evita funciones miembro innecesarias**

```
int ScoreManager::getOnlyInt(string pRow)
```

Esta función no necesita conocer el estado de `ScoreManager`, luego no tiene sentido que sea una función miembro. Lo suyo entonces podría ser cambiarla a función estática. ¿Motivo? Acceder a una función miembro requiere una indirección a través de `this`, mientras que el acceso a las funciones estáticas es inmediato:

```
class ScoreManager
{
  private:

    static int getOnlyInt(string const& row);
    //                           ^^^^^^ Hay que evitar copias innecesarias
};
```

**No abras dos ficheros si puedes evitarlo**

```
void ScoreManager::write_file(string pName, int pScore ){
  // ...
}
```

Esta función básicamente hace lo siguiente:

1. Añade al final de `"scores.txt"` la última puntuación.
2. <s>Cierra</s> dicho fichero (mentira, no lo cierra hasta el final) y lo lee para generar un vector. Nota que el comentario ya te advierte de un uso peligroso de los ficheros... lo estás abriendo con dos streams diferentes a la vez (uno de lectura y otro de escritura)
3. Ordena el array que se ha leído
4. Genera un nuevo fichero con la lista ordenada
5. Reemplaza el fichero antiguo por el nuevo.

¿Qué tal si?

1. Lees el fichero `"scores.txt"`.
2. Al final de la lista añades la nueva puntuación
3. Ordenas la lista
4. Sobreescribes el fichero.

Algo así:

```
void ScoreManager::write_file(string pName, int pScore ){
    const string file_name = "scores.txt";

    if (openFile(file_name, false)){
        closeFile();
    }

    vector<string> scores = getListScores();
    scores.push_back(to_string(pScore) + " " + pName);
    orderList(scores);

    ofstream fl(file_name , ios::trunc);
    if (fl.is_open()){
      std::for_each(scores.begin(),scores.end(),
                    [&fl](string const& score)
                    { fl << score << '\n'; });

      fl.close();    //Cierro el archivo score
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Error al abrir el archivo"<<endl;;
    }
}
```

**Utilizar estructuras de datos**

Gestionar las puntuaciones como una cadena de la que de repente empiezas a extraer los números tiene sus inconvenientes:

- para trabajar con las puntuaciones debes hacer conversiones continuas de string a entero
- ¿Qué sucede si algun *nick* tiene caracteres numéricos?

Lo recomendable sería almacenar las puntuaciones de forma estructurada:

```
struct Score
{
  int puntos;
  string nombre;
};
```

Esto desplaza la complejidad a la interacción con los ficheros, ya que el resto de las operativas serán mucho más sencillas.

**No reutilices variables**

Si revisas tu código verás que la variable `file_name` tiene un uso un tanto bizarro... ¿Es necesaria esa variable para compartir información entre funciones? La respuesta es que no y su uso únicamente complica la lectura del código. Hay que evitar, en la medida de lo posible, reutilizar variables. Esta práctica ayuda a detectar errores que de otra forma pasarían desapercibidos, como variables no inicializadas:

```
// ejemplo a evitar
int i=0,j;
for( i=0; i<10; i++)
  std::cout << i;
for( j=0; i<10; j++)
  std::cout << j; // Por que este bucle no aparece?

// ejemplo a seguir
for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
  std::cout << i;
for( int j=0; i<10; j++ ) // Ahora el compilador nos avisa del problema
  std::cout << j;
```

**No declares una variable hasta que no sea necesaria**

C++ no es un lenguaje basado en estándares antiguos de C, sino que es un lenguaje propio con sus propias características, ventajas e inconvenientes. Entre sus ventajas está que las variables se pueden declarar en casi cualquier punto del código.

Lo ideal, en línea con lo tratado en el punto anterior, es que las variables tengan una vida mínima imprescindible para cumplir su función y para poder hacer esto se hace necesario evitar declararlas todas en cascada al inicio de la función. Declarar las variables con un ámbito mínimo ayuda a detectar variables sin uso (y variables con demasiados usos) y ello te permite mantener el código más limpio y organizado.

Comment: Me encantan este tipo de respuestas! Muchas gracias por tomarte las molestia de escribir todo esto. :)

Comment: Compile con C++11 y anda bien. Pero me da error en estas lineas de la función "write_file"     vector<string> scores = getListScores();
    scores.push_back(to_string(pScore) + " " + pName);
    orderList(scores); //Aqui

Comment: @Sterlok piensa que te he dado varias opciones a elegir y no son compatibles entre sí... en cualquier caso sin decir qué error te da ni como ha quedado el código después de hacer tus cambios es dificil darte una respuesta.

Comment: he reemplazado 100% las funciones write_file() y orderList(), voy a poner el error en la pregunta